# Pandas - Merging 2 rows into 1 using

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Below a small example of a dataframe that i have. Every User have 2 rows and i want to merge the 2 into 1 row.

(Original dataframe)

```
USER       DETAIL          TEAM         VALUE
JohnDoe    Disponibily     Architect    107
JohnDoe    Capacity        Architect    240
JamesDean  Disponibily     Coder        80
JamesDean  Capacity        Coder        110
```

I'm trying to achieve something like this with pandas :

```
USER       TEAM            Disponibily  Capacity
JohnDoe    Architect       107          240
JamesDean  Coder           80           110
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use unstack, like: `df.set_index(['USER', 'TEAM', 'DETAIL'], inplace=True)` then `df.unstack(-1)`. Actually I was just writing an answer, when the question was marked as duplicate.

Comment: Please place your code in the question, so others can reproduce/solve the problem faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"USER":["JohnDoe","JohnDoe","JamesDean","JamesDean"],
                       "DETAIL":["Disponibily","Capacity","Disponibily","Capacity"],
                       "TEAM":["Architect","Architect","Coder","Coder"],
                       "VALUE":[107,240,80,110]})
res = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['USER','TEAM'],columns='DETAIL',values='VALUE').reset_index()
res.columns.name = ''
```

```
        USER    TEAM    Capacity    Disponibily
0    JamesDean  Coder       110       80
1    JohnDoe    Architect   240       107
```