# Merge rows with same Index and creating new columns for row da

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this `df`:

```
                Close
Symbol  Date    
AA  1/20/1998   29.530121
    1/14/2021   25.09
AIG 1/20/1998   485.831665
    1/14/2021   41.299999
AXP 1/20/1998   17.698372
... ... ...
WMT 1/14/2021   146.970001
XOM 1/20/1998   15.515985
    1/14/2021   50.310001
```

`Symbol` and `Date` are indexes. There are some exceptions where there is a symbol with only 1 date (WMT in the case of this example).

I want this:

```
    Start Date  End Date    Start Close End Close
Symbol              
AA  1/20/1998   1/14/2021   29.530121   25.09
AIG 1/20/1998   1/14/2021   485.831665  41.299999
AXP 1/20/1998   1/14/2021   17.698372   123.78
... ...         ...         ...         ...
VZ  1/20/1998   1/14/2021   14.96       57.040001
WMT 1/14/2021   Nan         146.970001  Nan
XOM 1/20/1998   1/14/2021   15.515985   50.310001
```

Other ways of dealing with the exception (WMT) are fine. I just envision taking the first date and assuming it's the start.

I found [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57149823/pandas-merging-2-rows-into-1-using) which suggests pivot tables for a similar issue but I have been unable the adapt it. I have tried this:

```
test1 = df.reset_index()
pd.pivot_table(test1,index=['Symbol'],columns='Date',values='Close')
```

which returns:

```
Date    1998-01-20  2021-01-14
Symbol      
AA  29.530121   25.090000
AIG 485.831665  41.299999
AXP 17.698372   123.779999
BA  27.150482   209.910004
... ...         ...
```

This merges `Symbol` gets `Close` in the same row, but doesn't deal with the dates how I'm trying to. I've since been checking the `pd.pivot_table` documentation but haven't been able to get any closer. Any suggestions, `pivot_table` or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a sample data and resetting the index

```
df = df.reset_index()

Symbol  Date    Close
0   AA  1/20/1998   29.530121
1   AA  1/14/2021   25.090000
2   AIG 1/20/1998   485.831665
3   AIG 1/14/2021   41.299999
4   WMT 1/14/2021   146.970001
5   XOM 1/20/1998   15.515985
6   XOM 1/14/2021   50.310001
```

You can groupby `Symbol` and take all the `Date` and `Close` in that group and create a single series of the two dates and the two closes, which would be taken up as a row corresponding the symbol

```
def func(df):
    dates = df['Date'].values.tolist()
    closes = df['Close'].values.tolist()
    if len(dates) == 1: # if there is one date,then End Date and End Close would be nans
        dates += [np.nan]
        closes += [np.nan]
    return pd.Series(dates + closes, index=['Start Date', 'End Date',
                                            'Start Close', 'End Close'])

df = df.groupby('Symbol')[['Date', 'Close']].apply(func)

df
    Start Date  End Date    Start Close End Close
Symbol              
AA  1/20/1998   1/14/2021   29.530121   25.090000
AIG 1/20/1998   1/14/2021   485.831665  41.299999
WMT 1/14/2021   NaN         146.970001  NaN
XOM 1/20/1998   1/14/2021   15.515985   50.310001
```

### EDIT:

There is an easier way to do it. You can use [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to create new columns. [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), which numbers each item in group, is used to know how many rows are there per group such that accordingly, columns can be updated.

```
out_df = df.set_index(['Symbol', df.groupby('Symbol').cumcount()]).unstack()
out_df.columns = [f'Start {c1}' if c2 == 0 else f'End {c1}' for c1, c2 in out_df.columns]
```

Comment: That works beautifully, thank you! Took me a while to validate it... had some additional data in my dataframe that was causing issues.

Comment: I have upated the answer. I found an easier way to get the solve the problem

Comment: Much simpler! Thank you for sharing.